# CSS text-decoration:underline doesn't work on a:visited selector

Tags: html5, css3

I have this snippet:

```
<p><a href="http://www.example.com">Link to example site.</a> </p>
```

---

```
a:link{
  color:green;
  text-decoration:none;
}


a:visited{
  color:pink;
  text-decoration:underline;
}

a:hover{
  color:yellow;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Can someone explain why the `text-decoration:underline;` for `a:visited` does not work?

Answer (score 6):

The functionality of `:visited` pseudoclass has been restricted in many modern browsers (Fx4, IE9, Chrome) to prevent CSS exploit. You can read about it [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/), but the crux is:

> For many years the CSS `:visited` selector has been a vector for querying a user’s history. It’s not particularly dangerous by itself, but when it’s combined with `getComputedStyle()` in JavaScript it means that someone can walk through your history and figure out where you’ve been.

Comment: And crucially, whilst some CSS properties (like `color`) can be changed, the browser "lies" when reading back the value and returns the default (unvisited) value for that property.

Answer (score 0):

The text-decoration has to be the same on every type of link.
Look at this question from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382698/css-pseudo-alink-overwriting-text-decoration-for-avisited)

When you remove your *text-decoration:none* from *a:link*, *a:visited* would be underlined.

Comment: No, i want my link to be underlined only after the link has been clicked. when i remove text-decoration:none from a:link by default the link is underlined